# When does it make sense to use a GPU?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have code doing a lot of operations with objects which can be represented as arrays.
When does it make to sense to use GPGPU environments (like CUDA) in an application? Can I predict performance gains before writing real code?

Comment: You could give more details about the most time consuming part of your code to enable others understand what exactly the operations are.

Comment: @Eric, the problem is it's quite big amount of code (machine learning && fuzzy computing). Just operations like plus, minus and etc with elements of array.

Comment: Vectors and Matrices. Sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convenience depends on a number of factors. Elementwise independent operations on large arrays/matrices are a good candidate.

For your particular problem (machine learning/fuzzy logic), I would recommend reading some related documents, as

[Large Scale Machine Learning using NVIDIA CUDA](http://adnanboz.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/large-scale-machine-learning-using-nvidia-cuda/)

and

[Fuzzy Logic-Based Image Processing Using Graphics Processor Units](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.158.5294&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

to have a feeling on the speedup achieved by other people.

Comment: _on large arrays/matrices_ Sorry, but what's large here, at what point does the GPU start paying off? matrix with 100 elements, 1000 elements 100k elements? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, you should specify your problem. However, if large parts of your code involve operations on your objects that are independent in a sense that object n does not have to wait for the results of the operations objects 0 to n-1, GPUs may enhance performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could go to CUDA Zone to get yourself a general idea about what CUDA can do and do better than CPU.

https://developer.nvidia.com/category/zone/cuda-zone

CUDA has already provided lots of performance libraries, tools and ecosystems to reduce the development difficulty. It could also help you understand what kind of operations CUDA are good at.

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-tools-ecosystem

Further more, CUDA provided benchmark report on some of the most common and representative operations. You could find if your code can benefit from that.

https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/CUDA_5.0_Math_Libraries_Performance.pdf